# Difficult MySQL Query to keep counting columns in sync

Tags: mysql, sql

Our 'users' database table has a number of counting columns that we want to keep in sync with content added by users to other tables such as 'photos'. We have been using the following to accomplish that:

```
update users u join (
    select user_id,count(*) as c
    from photos
    where status='A' group by user_id) p ON p.user_id=u.user_id
set u.photos=p.c;
```

We noticed recently however that if a user adds photos and then deletes all their photos, the query above never resets the 'photos' column to 0. The way photos are deleted is that the 'status' column in the 'photos' table is changed to status 'D'. I've tried a number of permutation of the above query without any luck.

I'm hoping someone with more MySQL expertise can suggest an updated query that correctly resets the 'photos' counting column in the 'users' table to 0. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need triggers, which fire up automatically in response to "events" in the database. e.g. if you have fields which depend on derived results in other fields/tables, you'd want triggers which will update those fields in response to insert/delete/update events.

Comment: Why are you storing things that can be easily caluclated 'on-the-fly'? Is there a significant performance benefit with this approach?

Comment: @Strawberry is correct, this can easily be achieved in a view. No need to store it.

Comment: Agree views/triggers would be better but we don't have the option of changing the code right now so just need to figure out how to fix the SQL query at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the join fails when there are no matches.  You can fix this by using conditional aggregation:

```
update users u join
       (select user_id, sum(status='A') as c
        from photos
        group by user_id
       ) p
       ON p.user_id = u.user_id
  set u.photos = p.c;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Gordon.